# Converting css with nested classes to styled components problem

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm having problems understanding nesting in styled components, i have a code i need to implement in my project but i don't fully understand how to write the same stuff with styled-comp. due to nesting of classes..

CSS:

```
#cf {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="cf">
  <img class="bottom" src="/images/Cirques.jpg" />
  <img class="top" src="/images/Clown%20Fish.jpg" />
</div>
```

I've been using styled-components for couple of weeks, so i understand the basics, i'm just having problems writing 2 nested objects like it's shown in css...

If u got time to explain it a bit, would be great :)

Answer (score 14):

it becomes:

```
import Styled from 'styled-components';

const MyDiv = Styled.div`
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;

  img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;

    &.top:hover{
       opacity:0;
    }
  }
`
```

### Render

```
<MyDiv />
```

### Working example

https://codesandbox.io/s/xj3y2qz87q

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try later! :)

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the documentation for [Pseudoelements, pseudoselectors, and nesting](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting), you could use your existing CSS as is as that would be how you would apply effects such as `:hover` anyway. Here is what that would look like applying your existing CSS to a styled-component:

```
const Foo = styled.div`
  #cf {
    position:relative;
    height:281px;
    width:450px;
    margin:0 auto;
  }

  #cf img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  }

  #cf img.top:hover {
    opacity:0;
  }
`;
```

Usage of the styled-component:

```
<Foo>
  <div id="cf">
    <img className="bottom" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/0000FF/808080" />
    <img className="top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/FF0000/FFFFFF" />
  </div>
</Foo>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-s98y3k) in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks dude, will try later :)

Answer (score 1):

When you implement your style rules, you might be surprised when they are not applied as expected.  The reason is how the **styled_components** works behind the scenes:

- it creates a <style> tag with attribute *data-styled="active"* and adds it to the <head> element
- it adds a random class name to the element being styled before any class names that you have added
- then it adds the style rules to its own <style> element, preceded by the random class name

This results in the style rule selector that works only for selector components that are in your element or children of your element.

But say you need to override a style rule in another stylesheet, that has a component with an id (i.e. preceded by #) from a parent DOM element.  You cannot use that #{some-id} selector in the rule you add to the styled component, because the order of the selector created for you begins with that random class name.  In this case, to get the selector to have the precedence required, you will have to nest another element (probably a div) with an #id, and use that #id in your style rule.